# Error Occured in while running android application

Tags: android

```
 [2014-08-07 11:31:09 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64;
 [2014-08-07 11:31:09 - Tut_login] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64
```

how to get out of this error...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you include several different classes with the same qualified name.

If it is the same file (that is, for example a library that's included several times), you have different version of that file. You have to ensure the same version of the library containing the file is used everywhere.

If they are different files, that is two files that occur to be named identically, but which where written by different person : this is a name clash. Refactor files until you got only one whose name is `Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64`

Answer (score 0):

You have two or more dependencies containing the same class (in your case, it's `org.kobjects.base64.Base64`. First make sure you don't have two dependencies of the same type, only a different version. Second, if you use Maven, you can use the "exclude" annotation, similar to how spring are doing it in this example:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```